# Error channel for message-driven-channel-adapter or JMS gateway

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jms, spring-jms

Can someone please help me with an issue that I've.

I've a service activator class that's common for a webservice gateway and a JMS adapter class (meaning I've request coming to this class from both webservices gateway channel and from MQ adapter channel).

And I'm throwing exceptions in this activator. I'm able to handle these exceptions for webservices flow as I've defined a error-channel in the gateway for webservices flow.

However, I can't handle these exceptions thrown while message is coming from an MQ.

Here is my WebService gateway :

```
<int:gateway id="avengersGenericServiceRestGateway" service-interface="com.foo.AvengersAnalysisProcessingV001" error-channel="avengersWsErrorChannel">
    <int:method name="hulcTransactionRisk" request-channel="hulcTransactionRiskAuthChannel" reply-channel="avengersGenericServiceOutputChannel" reply-timeout="1000" />
    <int:method name="hulcPartyRisk" request-channel="hulcPartyRiskAuthChannel" reply-channel="avengersGenericServiceOutputChannel" reply-timeout="1000" />
    <int:method name="callBlackWidow" request-channel="callBlackWidowAuthChannel" reply-channel="avengersGenericServiceOutputChannel" reply-timeout="1000" />
</int:gateway>
```

And here is my MQ adapter channel :

```
 <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter container="avengersEventMessageListenerContainer" channel="avengersExecutionFlowRouterChannel" />
```

I've been looking for options for defining an error-channel for jms-adapter, I couldn't find anything.

How can I have a error channel defined for the events coming from MQ into an JMS adapter.,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?

The message-driven channel adapter has had an error-channel since 2.0, 6+ years ago.

[commit here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/ed9a8d90a3a5cf60554dccd75e20adbd5017368f).

Perhaps you are looking at the old version-less schema on the internet; see the [*** Important Note ***](http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd) at the top as to why that has to continue to reflect the 1.0 schema.

Spring resolves the version-less schema from the jar on the classpath; it does not use the internet version.